# load .xib file and display it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, nib

I'm trying to display an "About Page" in my application when pressing a button, but when I press the UIButton, the NSLog(@"Button pressed") is called, but the view won't load. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)pushAbout {
    NSLog(@"Button pressed");
    AboutView * aboutView = [[AboutView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutView animated:YES];
    [aboutView release];
}
```

I've seen this code in an example, but it was called in a UITableViewController instead of an ordianry UIView controller.

The class files "AboutView" were created as UIViewController subclass. They were created and left untouched

Comment: Is there a AboutView.xib file in your bundle?

Comment: Yes, it was added together with AboutView.m and AboutView.h and contains just a Label

Comment: Does nothing happen? Or does just a white view show up? Is the AboutView.xib added to the target properly? And did you save your xib file? I sometimes edit my xib and forget to save...

Comment: Nothing happens. No view shows up. It's like the code simply ignores to load the view. What is ment by adding the .xib to the target?

Comment: Open Target -> Copy Bundle Resources, is your xib file in that list? Can you put a breakpoint in your action and see if aboutView is nil after initializing? If it's not nil try to present it as modalviewcontroller, please.

Comment: _nibName is "AboutView", that's all I could read out of the debugging info. I've got a copy of my project here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22139493/View.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you don't have a UINavigationController set.

Add

```
NSLog(@"nav? %@", self.navigationController);
```

to your action and you'll see that it dumps (null).

However, the AboutView.xib works fine if you enter this code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:aboutView animated:YES];
```

instead of

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutView animated:YES];
```

The view will show up. In you zipped example the AboutView.xib didn't contain a label, so don't wonder if it turns out to be a white page.

You can dismiss the presented modal view by using

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in your AboutViewController.

To get your hands on a UINavigationController I suggest creating an app with the Navigation-Based Application template.

Comment: Seems like i fogrot to save it. Anyways, the code works now. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2):

A guess: Your view is not in a UINavigationController, hence

```
self.navigationController
```

is actually `nil`, and nothing happens.

The solution would be to place the main view in a nav controller, and adding the nav controller's view to your application's main window.

A simple way of doing this:

In your app delegate, change

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

to

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
        initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Or similar. Note that this is just to get you started, and maybe not the nicest way of doing it. (I assumed you've just created a view-based application in xcode.)

Comment: I'm quite new to Obj-C. Any tutorial how do do that?  Edit:self is the mainViewController, the one who contains all outlets and actions of my buttons

Comment: Thanks, but the above worked well enough for me to use. Thank you again, anyways